# calculator app in svelte producing wrong result with certain numbers

Tags: javascript, svelte

i am watching a crash course in svelte that creates a calculator app, also a beginner in javascript, when i do `1.1 x 3` it produces the result pic below but when i do `1.1 x 4` it show the correct result `4.4`, anybody can figure out why?

**UPDATE: it is not a precision error, second code below is the solution**

```
<script lang="ts">
  const numbers = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "0", "."];
  const operations = ["/", "x", "-", "+", "="];

  let selectedOperation = "";
  let display = "";
  let firstNumber = "";
  let secondNumber = "";
  let isDisplayingResults = false;

  // the selected operation in the calculator
  const handleOperationClick = (operation: string) => {
    // prevent selecting operation if firstNumber is empty
    if (!firstNumber) return;
    // if "=" is clicked check if secondNumber is empty then no action, else
    if (operation === "=") {
      if (!secondNumber) return;
      // check if numbers has decimal point
      const hasDecimalfirst = /\./.test(firstNumber);
      const hasDecimalsecond = /\./.test(secondNumber);

      let firstNum;
      let secondNum;

      // parse first number as integer if no decimal point else parse as float
      if (!hasDecimalfirst) {
        firstNum = parseInt(firstNumber);
      } else {
        firstNum = parseFloat(firstNumber);
      }

      // parse second number as integer if no decimal point else parse as float
      if (!hasDecimalsecond) {
        secondNum = parseInt(secondNumber);
      } else {
        secondNum = parseFloat(secondNumber);
      }

      let results = "";

      // select operation based on selected operation
      switch (selectedOperation) {
        case "/":
          results = (firstNum / secondNum).toFixed(2);
          break;
        case "x":
          if (!hasDecimalfirst || !hasDecimalsecond) {
            results = (firstNum * secondNum).toString();
          } else {
            results = (firstNum * secondNum).toFixed(2);
          }
          break;
        case "+":
          if (!hasDecimalfirst || !hasDecimalsecond) {
            results = (firstNum + secondNum).toString();
          } else {
            results = (firstNum + secondNum).toFixed(2);
          }
          break;
        case "-":
          if (!hasDecimalfirst || !hasDecimalsecond) {
            results = (firstNum - secondNum).toString();
          } else {
            results = (firstNum - secondNum).toFixed(2);
          }
          break;
      }
      display = results;
      isDisplayingResults = true;
    }
    selectedOperation = operation;
  };

  const handleClear = () => {
    firstNumber = "";
    secondNumber = "";
    selectedOperation = "";
    display = "";
    isDisplayingResults = false;
  };
  // the handler when selecting numbers in the calculator
  const handleNumberClick = (number: string) => {
    // clear all values after displaying the result when selecting a number
    if (isDisplayingResults) {
      handleClear();
    }
    // if display is empty and selected number is 0 then no action
    // does not allow the initial number 0 assuming not float
    if (!display && number === "0") return;
    // if selected number is . and display already has . then no action
    // does not allow more than one .
    if (number === "." && display.includes(".")) return;

    // no selected operation yet
    if (!selectedOperation) {
      // if display is empty and selected number is . assign to firstNumber then display
      if (!display && number === ".") {
        firstNumber = "0.";
        return (display = firstNumber);
      }
      // if display is not empty append to current display and assign to firstNumber
      firstNumber = `${firstNumber}${number}`;
      return (display = firstNumber);
    } else {
      // already have a selected operation
      // if display is empty and selected number is . assign to secondNumber then display
      if (!display && number === ".") {
        secondNumber = "0.";
        return (display = secondNumber);
      }
      // if display is not empty append to current display and assign to secondNumber
      secondNumber = `${secondNumber}${number}`;
      return (display = secondNumber);
    }
  };
</script>

<main>
  <div class="calculator">
    <div class="results">{display}</div>
    <div class="digits">
      <div class="numbers">
        <button class="btn btn-xlg" on:click={handleClear}>C</button>
        {#each numbers as number (number)}
          <button
            class={`btn ${number === "0" ? "btn-lg" : null}`}
            on:click={() => handleNumberClick(number)}
          >
            {number}
          </button>
        {/each}
      </div>
      <div class="operations">
        {#each operations as operation (operation)}
          <button
            class={`btn ${operation === selectedOperation ? "btn-silver" : "btn-orange"}`}
            on:click={() => handleOperationClick(operation)}
          >
            {operation}
          </button>
        {/each}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>
```

[image]

**SOLUTION:**

```
  // check if numbers has decimal point
  const hasDecimalFirst = /\./.test(firstNumber);
  const hasDecimalSecond = /\./.test(secondNumber);

  // Parse numbers as integers if no decimal point, else parse as floats
  const parseNumber = (number: string) => {
    return hasDecimalFirst || hasDecimalSecond
      ? parseFloat(number)
      : parseInt(number);
  };

  const firstNum = parseNumber(firstNumber);
  const secondNum = parseNumber(secondNumber);

  let results = "";

  // Perform the selected operation
  switch (selectedOperation) {
    case "/":
      results = (firstNum / secondNum).toFixed(2);
      break;
    case "x":
      results = (firstNum * secondNum).toFixed(
        hasDecimalFirst || hasDecimalSecond ? 2 : 0
      );
      break;
    case "+":
      results = (firstNum + secondNum).toFixed(
        hasDecimalFirst || hasDecimalSecond ? 2 : 0
      );
      break;
    case "-":
      results = (firstNum - secondNum).toFixed(
        hasDecimalFirst || hasDecimalSecond ? 2 : 0
      );
      break;
```